# Deniability properties of the X3DH Key Agreement Protocol

Tags: signature, diffie-hellman, key-exchange, plausible-deniability

Signal's [X3DH Key Agreement Protocol specification](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/#signatures) states in section 4.5.:

> Alternatively, it might be tempting to replace the DH-based mutual authentication (i.e. DH1 and DH2) with signatures from the identity keys. However, this reduces deniability, [...]

How exactly does replacing `DH1` and `DH2` with signatures **reduce** deniability?

Answer (score 1):

I think, using of signatures means something like STS protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol).
In STS, for the purpose of mutual authentication, 
each party must send a signature of ephemeral keys.
So, in terms used in https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh ,
Alice should sign `EK_a || SPK_b`, and Bob should sign the same.

In X3DH, authentication provided by signatures is substituted by 
the fact that for getting the key (`SK`) each party should execute DH exchange using his identity key (say, `ID_a`) and counter-party's ephemeral key (say, `SPK_b`). So, in fact, signing of `SPK_b` with private key of `ID_a` (in STS) is substituted with just running of DH for `ID_a` and `SPK_b` (in X3DH).

So, what's the difference for deniability? Very simple: signature is evidence of communication and knowing of ephemeral keys, and hence knowing of `SK`. While running of DH is not an evidence, because it's even impossible to know wether Bob (or Alice) run DH and get `SK` or not.
If Alice will want to prove to some judge that Bob communicated with her,
and Bob knows some `SK` (and hence - he could create or at least decrypt some cypher-texts provided by Alice to judge), she can't prove it:
it's obvious that Alice could simulate DH with any `EK_a` key she wants. There's no evidence that Bob was running DH with `EK_a` and even know about existence of such `EK_a`.

Answer (score 0):

**Signatures are verifiable by a third party**—any party knowing the public key can verify signed messages, but that's not enough to forge them.

If Alice wants to persuade Charlie that Bob wrote a message and Alice has Bob's signature on it, Charlie can verify that signed message using Bob's public key with no threat of violence.

**Symmetric authenticators under secrets from DH key agreements are not verifiable by a third party**—any party that can verify message authenticators can also forge them.

If Alice wants to persuade Charlie that Bob wrote a message and there's only a symmetric authenticator on the message, not only could Alice have forged the authenticator but in order to enable Charlie to verify the authenticator Alice has to reveal her own secret keys, or under threat of violence cause Bob to reveal his own.

Thus, when Bob has signed a message that may later work against his interests, there's an easy way for Alice to persuade Charlie that Bob wrote it—but when Bob has only provided a symmetric authenticator, Charlie has no way to tell whether Bob actually sent it or whether Alice forged it, giving Bob an easy way to deny it.

Comment: That is not very accurate. after every signature you can demand the signer to give up her secret key. In that way the signature you could have been forged by anyone.

Comment: Yes—third-party verifiability is premised on the signer keeping the signing key secret.  I don't understand the point you're making here.  With signatures, third parties can verify as long as the signing key is secret; with symmetric authenticators, third parties can never verify because the verification procedure requires a secret key, knowledge of which is also sufficient for forgery.  Thus there is a reasonable situation in which signatures admit third-party verification while symmetric authenticators never do.  In what way is my answer not accurate?

Comment: One party of the communication always passes the secret keys to the third parties. So be it signature or MAC the third party can always verify. In the MAC scheme it can be either parties who have sent the message: that provides deniability. The same can be achieved with the signatures if you open your secret key each time you send a signature. A similar approach is followed by OTR protocol. It is also dependant on what you are signing: If the signature does not contain any ID then still it could be anyone holding the key

Comment: If Alice wants to persuade Charlie that Bob wrote a message and _Alice has Bob's signature on it_, Charlie can verify that signature using Bob's public key with no threat of violence.  If Alice wants to persuade Charlie that Bob wrote a message and there's only a _symmetric authenticator_ on the message, not only could Alice have forged the authenticator but in order to enable Charlie to verify the authenticator Alice has to reveal her own secret keys, or under threat of violence cause Bob to reveal his own.  Still don't understand your objection, or how OTR reveals signature _keys_.

Comment: @curious Also, a signature _may_ identify a user even if you don't deliberately put a user id in it—this was used, for instance, to [break the privacy of the PLAID smartcard protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/728).  I would be curious to understand what your continued objection to this post is, if you would care to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly does replacing DH1 and DH2 with signatures **reduce** deniability?

$$\begin{aligned}
k &= \text{kdf}(A^{b_e} \| A^{b}_e \| A^{b_e}_e)\\
  &= \text{kdf}(B^{a}_e \| B^{a_e} \| B^{a_e}_e)
\end{aligned}$$

Diffie-Hellman can be computed by "either Alice or Bob", however, the question of which computed the shared key is not revealed. If Alice knows Bob's public key, but has not interacted with Bob, she may forge a transcript under Signal's protocol.

$$\begin{aligned}
k &= \text{kdf}(A^{b_e}_e)\\
  &= \text{kdf}(B^{a_e}_e)\\
s_A &= \text{sign}_a(A_e)\\
s_B &= \text{sign}_b(B_e)
\end{aligned}$$

Signatures, by definition are not deniable and their mere presence implies some communication occurred. If Alice and Carol exchange private messages and either Carol, or the signal servers, or a MiTM leaks the signed ephemeral $s_A$; then Bob can still forge a transcript. Bob relies on such a leak so he cannot forge a transcript with **any** user.

Because Bob cannot forge a transcript with just anyone; Alice is going to have a harder time disputing having ever communicated with Bob, although because deniability was only reduced and not broken, she may succeed. This is the only leakage. The transcript remains deniable thanks to [Double Ratchet](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/).

$s_B$ is implied by Signal's signed prekey bundles; although it has additional structure so the semi-ephemeral cannot be mistakened as a fresh ephemeral.

---

On the other hand so long that the average user **cannot** forge transcripts because the Signal application does not expose such a feature; the deniability can be disputed not only for the liklihood that the handshake occurred, but can "prove" to a degree using forensic analysis that the transcript was not forged.

Worse, many people will blindly accept a screenshot without signatures nor other authenticators or proofs of identity.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong.

When we understand deniability, we should also understand what non-deniability is. To achieve non-deniability, each message needs to contain the digital signature of the sender private key. After receiving the message, the receiver can use the public key of the sender to verify the message content. If the authentication is passed, the message is non-deniability. Although the X3DH protocol representation and the corresponding libsignal-protocol-javascript in the signal sdk show the Mac part of the message content, the digital signature of the message content is not seen. Adding a Mac to the message content only supports proof of message integrity and is not sufficient to support that the message came from the sender.

So this is my point to understand the deniability of x3dh this way.